# Movie with crashed UFO and floor panels that light up (and kill the people standing on them)

Tags: story-identification, movie

Looking for a sci-fi movie, probably late 1950's or early 1960's.  I'm pretty sure that it was B&W.  The only thing I can remember is that people were trying to walk across what I think was a crashed UFO. The panels would light up, and if they were on them at that time they would collapse (and die I think). 
I know that it's not much to go on, but I was young, and I've never been able to figure this out.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it's a movie? The scene you describe reminds me of the City of Exxilon in the Doctor Who serial _[Death to the Daleks](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Death_to_the_Daleks)_. That would have been in the 1970's though. And it was in colour.

Comment: Pretty sure it was a movie and not something like Twilight Zone or Dr. Who.  Thanks for the response though.

Comment: I remember the movie but not the title. I believe it also featured a nuclear submarine and an alien ship under the ice at the North Pole. The alien ship had the glowing panels you describe. I'd love to find this movie too. Markf

Comment: Possibly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Atomic_Submarine, but probably not https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Thing_from_Another_World.

Answer (score 1):

*[The Atomic Submarine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Atomic_Submarine)* is definitely the film mentioned by Markf.  Whether it is the one meant in the original question, I am not entirely certain.

The film can be seen in its entirety [here](http://xmovies8.fm/watch/kvXw85de-the-atomic-submarine.html).  (**I make no warrantee that the linked site is free of malware, but it did not do anything to my Mac.**)  The scene with the dangerous floor lights in the UFO is at 1:01:35.  The glowing panels do not actually kill anybody in that scene, but two people are killed on the same walkways earlier in the film (0:55:10 and 0:59:50).